# What are the differences between Katalon studio and Katalon recorder?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder, katalon

I would like have automation tests using Katalon. I have seen there are two options, Katalon studio and Katalon recorder.
Can you please tell me and explain what are the differences between them? Each one has a different purpose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Katalon Recorder is a record-and-playback automation tool, geared more to beginners and quick recorder tests. Similar to Selenium IDE.

Katalon Studio is a broad tool that includes the Recorder, but also scripting, test cases and test suites, reporting, API testing. It also includes an Eclipse-style Groovy IDE.